# AVL rotation balance factor

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm implementing a AVL BST, however, I can't make sense about the balance phase.
I have the following code:

```
#ifndef AVLARBRE_HH
#define AVLARBRE_HH
#include "BSTArbre.hh"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "FoodPackage.hh"

template <class K, class V>
class AVLArbre : public BSTArbre<K, V> {
private:
    float iva = 0;

public : 
    AVLArbre() : BSTArbre<K, V>(){};
    AVLArbre(const AVLArbre<K, V> &orig) : BSTArbre<K, V>(orig) {};
    AVLArbre(const BSTNode<K, V> &r) : BSTArbre<K, V>(r) {};

    //legeix un avl des d'un fitxer de prova
    AVLArbre(const string &path, float iva) : AVLArbre(path)
    {
        this->iva = iva;

    }
    AVLArbre(const string& path) {
        ifstream file(path);
        if (!file.is_open()) {
            throw runtime_error("No s'ha pogut obrir el fitxer");
        }
        string line;
        string date_time;
        string product_id;
        float price;
        int amount;
        getline(file, line); // skip els headers
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, date_time, ',');
            getline(ss, product_id, ',');
            ss >> price;
            ss.ignore();
            ss >> amount;
            FoodPackage f(date_time, product_id, price, amount);
            insert(date_time, {f});
        }
        file.close();
    }

    int difference() {
        return difference(this->root);
    }


    int difference(BSTNode<K, V> *node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return 0;
        }
        return node->height() - max(height(node->getLeft()), height(node->getRight()));
    }

    int height(BSTNode<K, V> *node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return 0;
        }
        return node->height();
    }

    int max(int a, int b) {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }

    BSTNode<string, FoodPackage> *search(const string &key) const
    {
        return BSTArbre<K, V>::search(key);
    }

    void printInorder() const
    {
        printInorder(this->root);
    }

    void printInorder(const int n) const
    {
        BSTArbre<K, V>::printInorder(n);
    }

    BSTNode<K, V> *rr_rotation(BSTNode<K, V> *node)
    {
        cout << "balancing rr" << endl;
        BSTNode<K,V>* aux = node->getRight();
        node->setRight(aux->getLeft());
        aux->setLeft(node);
        return aux;
    }

    BSTNode<K, V>* ll_rotation(BSTNode<K, V>* node) {
        cout << "balancing ll" << endl;
        BSTNode<K, V>* aux = node->getLeft();
        node->setLeft(aux->getRight());
        aux->setRight(node);
        return aux;
    }

    BSTNode<K, V>* rl_rotation(BSTNode<K, V>* node) {
        cout << "balancing rl" << endl;
        BSTNode<K, V>* aux = node->getRight();
        node->setRight(ll_rotation(aux));
        return rr_rotation(node);
    }

    BSTNode<K, V>* lr_rotation(BSTNode<K, V>* node) {
        cout << "balancing lr" << endl;
        BSTNode<K, V>* aux = node->getLeft();
        node->setLeft(rr_rotation(aux));
        return ll_rotation(node);
    }

    BSTNode<K, V>* balance(BSTNode<K, V>* node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        int d = difference(node);
        if (d == 2) {
            if (difference(node->getLeft()) > 0) {
                return ll_rotation(node);
            } else {
                return lr_rotation(node);
            }
        } else if (d == -2) {
            if (difference(node->getRight()) > 0) {
                return rr_rotation(node);
            } else {
                return rl_rotation(node);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    BSTNode<K, V>* insert(K key, V value) {
        BSTNode<K, V>* node = BSTArbre<K, V>::insert(key, value);
        return balance(node);
    }
...
```

I think the overall logic is good, but I don't know how to implement the `difference` function. When I'm inserting one new `BSTNode`, the left and right childs are `nullptr`, so each time the `difference` functions is called it's returning 1. Should I be calling it over the `parent` of the node? I'm sorry, I don't get this rotation stuff.

Comment: Re-trace what got you implementing AVL-trees. If it was an assignment, the main idea should have been introduced: Provide to determine in O(1) time for any node whether it is balanced, of which child(-tree) is higher and lower. A&V-L argued to use two bits, and somehow hide then in the node's data. Currently, `int difference(BSTNode<K, V> *node)` checks one useful invariant about the `height()` of the loosely related type `BSTNode<K, V>` - it will be the same for any `parent`.

Comment: @greybeard not an assigment, end the uni some years ago, but never touched this topic.

Comment: (damn typos) Main idea: Provide to determine in O(1) time for any node whether it is balanced, **or** which child(-tree) is higher and lower. A&V-L argued to use two bits, and somehow hide **them** in the node's data.

Answer (score 0):

`difference(BSTNode<K, V> *node)` should return the difference in height between children, if any: just

```
    /** return difference between height of right and left sub-tree, if any. */
    int difference(BSTNode<K, V> const &node) {
        return node == nullptr ? 0
            : height(node->getLeft()) - height(node->getRight());
    }
```

`int balance()` would seem a more conventional name, and it better be a member of (`BS`)`TNode`.

Comment: `overall logic is good`. Maybe. I happen to dislike a height to be kept with every node. (and undocumented source code.) (and non-const pointers where const ref would do.)

Comment: (didn't check whether "direction of difference" matches use in `AVLArbre`.)

Comment: (had a peek: looks reversed)

Comment: The thing is that `BSTNode<K, V>* insert(K key, V value)` inserts a new node in the tree, however left and right child are nullptrs, so `difference` in `balance` is always 0. That's the thing I don't know how to address

Comment: ? balance 0 is perfect: nothing to do! (And it is the *difference in height* that is zero: *balance 0* (or *balance factor*).)

Comment: the problem is that always is 0, because of the way of inserting the new node, even when it should be balanced

Comment: `the problem is [the balance of the additional leaf] always is 0` No, that's by definition. The problem is that you try to balance the new leaf instead of the node that might have gone out of balance. [Name (and or cite)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) an accessible resource you are trying to follow implementing AVL.